# Mirror image read from 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, image, file, 2d

I am writting a program in C in which i'm reading a bmp image with a 2D array. I am supposed to have as output the original image + its inverse **right** next to each other.

The code I have here should be doing that but the images print on **top** of each other. I appreciate the help if anyone knows how I can fix that.

```
int main(void) {

    // Opens file to read the image from
    FILE * infile = fopen("inputImage.bmp", "rb");

    // Creates file to write the image to after modifications     
    FILE * outfile = fopen("flip.bmp", "wb");

    //Bmp images have headers the next 3 lines of code store the header of the input image
    unsigned char headersPart1[2];
    int filesize;    
    unsigned char headersPart2[48];

    // This space[] [] creates the array to which to write the input image AND its inverse right next to each other  the image file is 160 * 240
    // The 3 is for the rgb values.. since its a 2D array we want to use every single //part of the image to work with    
    unsigned char space[160][3*240]; 

    //The array to which to copy the results to (original image + INVERSE) 
    unsigned char mirror[160][3*480]; 

    fread(headersPart1,sizeof(char) ,2,infile);
    fread(&filesize,sizeof(char) ,4,infile);
    fread(headersPart2,sizeof(char) ,48,infile);  
    fread(space,sizeof(char) ,filesize-54,infile);  

    // copying what in the original image array (space[][]) into the new //array mirror[][]
    for ( int row = 0; row < 240*3 ; row++ ) {
        for (int col = 0 ; col < 160; col++) {

            char temp = space[col][row];
            mirror[col][row] = space[col][row];

            //Starts printing the inverse of the original image, starting at the index where the original image will end
            mirror[col][720+row]=  space[col][719-row];

            space[col][row] = temp;

        }
    }

    // Puts everything back into the outfile , once i save and run on GCC this gives me an image and its inverse on top of each other
    fwrite(headersPart1,sizeof(char) ,2,outfile);
    fwrite(&filesize,sizeof(char) ,4,outfile);
    fwrite(headersPart2,sizeof(char) ,48,outfile);

    //sends whats in mirror [][] to the outfile
    //54 is the size of the header (bmp images))
    fwrite(mirror,sizeof(char) ,filesize-54,outfile);    

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I'm running this on GCC

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on in your code (that's what comments are for), I'm guessing the image has a height of `160px` and a width of `(3 * 240 * 2)px`? So the resulting image should have a height of `160px` and a width of `2 * (3 * 240 * 2)px`? And what is the purpose of `char temp` in the double for loop?

Comment: @Jonny Henly . Ill add comments now

Comment: Those comments are great : ) but I'm still confused as to what `temp` , in the nested for loop, is used for? Is `temp` just an artifact from a previous version of your code?

Comment: Temp is just a variable to store the current location on the image just in case assigning copying that image to the new array damages it , I put back temp at the same spot when im done. I guess it could be avoided but then again im new to C so i like to play it safe

Answer (score 0):

[The BMP file format you can find here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Your loader is not complete regarding support different versions of BMP, check resolution, color-depth, the presens of palette etc.

But for what you want to use this for, you probably have a fixed input, always the same resolution etc.

But you want the resulting image to be twice as wide. Hence some details in the headers has to change:

"filesize"
"the bitmap width in pixels (signed integer)"